# SQL get unique id per user

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I group the statement by their user_id, i keep getting duplicates of 2 and 3 already used a group by on the user_id? What seems to be the error?

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM users INNER JOIN
     user_privileges 
     ON users.id = user_privileges.user_id 
GROUP BY user_id, amount 
ORDER BY user_id;

+---------+-------------+
| user_id | SUM(amount) |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |     3000.00 |
|       2 |     2500.00 |
|       2 |    19000.00 |
|       3 |     2500.00 |
|       3 |    19000.00 |
|       4 |    12000.00 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Remove amount field from GROUP BY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to simply group by `userid`, not `amount`:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount)
FROM users INNER JOIN
     user_privileges 
     ON users.id = user_privileges.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

However, the `join` does not even seem to be necessary.  You can just do:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount)
FROM user_privileges 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_privileges 
ON users.id = user_privileges.user_id 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Comment: I still get 2 and 3 duplicates how come ?

Comment: you don't need `amount` as grouping candidate. doing so with `user_id` will extract data grouped by both of these fields. See the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct (user_id), SUM(amount) 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_privileges 
on users.id = user_privileges.user_id 
GROUP BY user_id, amount 
ORDER BY user_id;
```

Comment: I still get 2 and 3 duplicates how come ?